# edit node coordinate in qgis, moving a point without having to make another layer

Tags: pyqgis, layers, point

so I wanted to make a script, but I am not good using the qgis api...

To sum up the issue I have this :

[image]

I want that the 3 points of the yellow polygon are snapped by the closest point of other layers (example an orange point will snap to a point of the yellow layer).

Right now in my script I have the list of all the points coordinate, list of the selected figure, I found out the closest distance. But I am stucked on trying to move the points of the other layers to make them snap to the nodes of the yellow layer... And I don't want to make new layers to do this and I don't want to do it manually, I want to edit the existing coordinates of the points of the other layers...

Here is my script right now : 
https://pastebin.com/KYjFdEyn

I found out on the qgis api that there is method setgeometry but I have no idea how to use, even when I read the doc... Unless I am looking at the bad thing, I am not even sure it will be able to do what I want.

Does anyone have an idea on how to edit the coordinate of points of a layer ?

Comment: I think that the best way for doing that is generating all vertex point for each feature because 'moveVertex' method of **QgsVectorLayer** has as parameters a **QgsPoint** of target feature and id and number vertex of feature source.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is the good solution, that is what you showed in your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that the 3 points of the yellow polygon are snapped by the closest point of other features you will have errors because some of them are coincident.

I think that the best way for doing that is generating all vertex point for each feature because 'moveVertex' method of **QgsVectorLayer** has as parameters a **QgsPoint** of target feature and id and number vertex of feature source.

Next code produces a memory layer where into its attributes table has above information.

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

layer = registry.mapLayersByName('again')

feats = [ feat for feat in layer[0].getFeatures() ]

polygons = [ feat.geometry().asPolygon() for feat in feats ]

num_vertex_feats = [ len(polygon[0]) - 1 for polygon in polygons ] 

idx = [ [i,j] for i, num in enumerate(num_vertex_feats) for j in range(num) ]

points = [ feats[i].geometry().vertexAt(j) for i, num in enumerate(num_vertex_feats) for j in range(num) ]

epsg = layer[0].crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer&field=i:integer&field=j:integer&field=x:real&field=y:real""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'point',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(points)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i, idx[i][0], idx[i][1], points[i][0], points[i][1]])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(points[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running it at Python Console of QGIS, I got point layer of next image.

[image]

Information to move points is in next block:

```
target
id: 1, i: 0, j: 1, x: 408268.114929, y: 4441699.98256
source
id: 4, i: 1, j: 0, x: 412427.500504, y: 4439668.65472
target
id: 2, i: 0, j: 2, x: 402561.051, y: 4437637.32688
source
id: 6, i: 1, j: 2, x: 414362.098446, y: 4432220.45265
target
id: 5, i: 1, j: 1, x: 433804.807761, y: 4432607.37223
source
id: 9, i: 2, j: 2, x: 433321.158276, y: 4433671.4011
```

Following small code portion does the vertex movement for the first target-source pair.

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

layer = registry.mapLayersByName('again')

layer[0].startEditing()

layer[0].moveVertex(408268.114929, 4441699.98256, 1, 0)

layer[0].commitChanges()
```

After running it, you have first pair snapped; as it can be observed at next image:

[image]

next code portion for movement is:

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

layer = registry.mapLayersByName('again')

layer[0].startEditing()

layer[0].moveVertex(402561.051, 4437637.32688, 1, 2)

layer[0].commitChanges()
```

and the last one is:

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

layer = registry.mapLayersByName('again')

layer[0].startEditing()

layer[0].moveVertex(433804.807761, 4432607.37223, 2, 2)

layer[0].commitChanges()
```

Final result was as expected (all features snapped):

[image]

Best performance of all necessary code would be in a plugin.